# Массовая замена в строке по ключу ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, replace

Есть программка, которая заменяет найденный в файле текст на "пустоту"

```
 //просто считываем правила удаления (выводим элементы ArrayList)
    Read r = new Read();
    r.reader();
    for (Rules newUser : r.mass) {
        System.out.println(newUser.key);
    }

// производим замену
String replace = "";
        for (Rules newUser : r.mass) {
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            Files.write(path, new String(Files.readAllBytes(path),     charset).replace(newUser.key, replace).getBytes(charset));
            count++;
        }
```

в mass - содержимое ArrayList, которое считывается из файла.

```
BufferedReader readFromFile = null;
    try {
        // указываем с какого файла будем считывать правила
       // readFromFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/123.txt"));
        readFromFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/123.txt"));
        //заполняем ArrayList строками из файла
        while ((line = readFromFile.readLine()) != null) {
            Rules newRules = new Rules();
            newRules.key = line;
            mass.add(newRules);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (readFromFile != null)
            try {
                readFromFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Нужно делать замену не на "пустоту", а на содержимое другого файла.
Могу считать его и записать в другой ArrayList, но не пойму, как выполнить саму замену?

Т.е. replace должен содержать не константу, а значения ArrayList и должно заменять так:
**Первая строка из файла1 на первая строка из файла2 и т.д.**

Подробнее:
Есть файл xxx, в котором производится замена. Есть файл rules, в котором содержится список, ЧТО нужно заменить. 
Есть файл rules2, в котором содержится список НА ЧТО нужно заменить. 
Есть код, котрый считывает файлы rules и rules2 в ArrayList-ы. 
Есть код, который выполняет замену в файле xxx - ищет значения из файла rules, которые в ArrayList, и заменяет на String-вую константу. 
А нужен код, который будет выполнять замену в файле xxx на содержимое из файла rules2, которые в другом ArrayList

Comment: Первую строку в первом файле нужно заменить на первую строку во втором файле? И так для всех? Количество строк в файлах одинаковое?

Comment: нет, замена производится в другом файле. Просто правила замены в двух отдельных файлах. 
Понимаю, это не оптимально, можно было бы как-то работать с одним файлом, где правила будут разделены разделителем, но я решил взять за основу код, который уже есть у меня.

Да. Количество строк одинаковое

Comment: Необходимо заменить содержимое первого ArrayList на второго ArrayList?Это спрашиваете?

Comment: Есть файл xxx, в котором производится замена. Есть файл rules, в котором содержится список, ЧТО нужно заменить. Есть файл rules2, в котором содержится список НА ЧТО нужно заменить. Есть код, котрый считывает файлы rules и rules2 в ArrayList-ы. Есть код, который выполняет замену в файле xxx - ищет значения из файла rules, которые в ArrayList, и заменяет на String-вую константу. А нужен код, который будет выполнять замену в файле xxx на содержимое из файла rules2, которые в другом ArrayList